# Appmaker multiple filters on one page

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a page where I need to display projects from one table according to there status - I need To Do, In Progress, Done like on kanban board. I tried to filter each panel according to status but I guess because I filter the same datasource I end up with the same data in all three panels. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two options come to mind:

1. Use one datasource, but 3 tables, for each table, bind the Table Row's visible property to the item's status like: @datasource.item.status === "Done", etc. And then for the other two tables do the same but with a different status value, this will basically just hide the rows that don't match your desired status.
2. Use 3 datasources, and either have a query that loads a specific status, or let the user filter within that status using query filters (@datasource.query.filters.type._equals = "Done"). This way each table is its own datasource and set of records that does not overlap.

Comment: Thanks. I already used option 2 but option 1 also seems reasonable in some cases.